# PHP with Rest API current() in While loop

Tags: php, angular, ionic2

I am developing an Mobile app in angular2 with PHP Rest API. I am sending data from ionic2 front-end, it is perfectly coming.

The problem is when I get that data values in while loop with `current()` it is not entering to the loop.

But if I pass static values like below `$chkLead=["648","647"];` Its is entering perfectly fine and executing the while loop and performing the back-end update operation.

My Front-end values are coming in the same way as I am sending statically `["648","647"]`.

```
 //$chkLead=["648","647"];
   $chkLead;
   while ($new_lead = current($chkLead)) {
       $lead_id = current($chkLead);
       $whereupdateleads = array('id = ?' => $lead_id);
       $tableSalesLeads->update($leadsUpdateValues, $whereupdateleads);
       echo json_encode($whereupdateleads);
       exit;
  }
```

And if I use `key()` with static values inside while loop `$lead_id = key($chkLead);` also not performing update operation. So I am using `current()` instead of `key()` in `$lead_id = current($chkLead);` and it is working fine with static values and updating back-end operation.

Below is the error message I am getting :

```
 SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
at Object.parse (native)
at Response.Body.json
```

Thank you

Comment: It has been years since I last used PHP. It looks like you are only using `current()`, which does not move the pointer. Also, I'm not sure why you are using `exit;` inside the loop. This means that the program will finish after the first iteration. Couldn't you just use a simple `foreach`?

Where exactly do you get the error you posted? In your backend or in your Ionic app? Can you post the output of your script?

Comment: @AndreasGassmann thank you for your reply.  I solved it by using For loop instead of while loop. The error is in back-end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem myself by using For loop instead of While loop as suggested by @AndreasGassmann

Thank you.